# multiple versiones con operador or

Tags: python, pip

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema a la hora de especificar ciertas dependencias para un paquete en python.

La cosa es simple, mi paquete necesita cierta librería disponible para instalar vía pip, solo que se instalara desde un .whl descargado localmente.

La cosa es que en dependencia de ciertas condiciones ese .whl descargado puede tener dos versiones, digamos 1.0 y 2.o, y necesito especificar en las dependencias de mi paquete que necesita una de esas dos versiones.

Algo así sería mi ruequirements.txt. Por más que leo la documentación oficial no logro descifrar como hacer esto. Gracias de antemano

```py
mydependencia (==1.0 or ==2.0)
```

Comment: si nos dices de que dependencia se trata creo que sera mas facil de resolver tu probñema, ademas en el `requirements.txt` solo se especifca una version, ya que es la se instalara al ejecutar el programa desde 0

Comment: se trata de keras y las versiones son 2.1.4 y 2.2.5. Tienes razon, pero en el requirements puedes especificar por ejemplo un rango de versiones. Keras>=1.0.0,<2.0.0 pero esto no es lo que necesito

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, de ese modo me funciona como queria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras leer la especificación en el [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) que es la referencia definitiva sobre los especificadores de dependencias, parece que la única forma de lograr lo que quieres es especificar una serie de condiciones separadas por comas, que pip interpretará como `and` (es decir, que deben cumplirse todas ellas). En tu caso podrías especificar que la versión sea mayoro igual a `2.1.4` y menor o igual a `2.2.5` y distinta de cada una de las versiones intermedias entre esas dos. Es decir:

```
keras >=2.1.4, <=2.2.5, !=2.1.5, !=2.1.6, !=2.2.0, !=2.2.1, !=2.2.2, !=2.2.3, !=2.2.4
```

Comment: La primera variante me funciona. Muestra unos warnings pero todo bien

Comment: Pues lo he eliminado de la respuesta, porque creo que no es para eso. La sintaxis de corchetes es para especificar "extras" y no versiones. Mira el [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#extras)

Comment: tienes razon, de echo ese es el warning, WARNING: Keras 2.2.5 does not provide the extra '2.2.5'